# how to remove arraylist value in elastic search using curl?

Tags: elasticsearch, arraylist, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How to remove arraylist values in Elasticsearch using sense console or curl?

i want to remove any array element.?

```
POST /q/q/
{
    "a": [
    "z", "q", "1"
    ]
}
```

it doesnt work for me:

```
POST /q/q/AV4sjk40mWHLgYFNkmNd/_update
{
    "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "inline": "ctx._source.a -=newsupp",
        "params": {
            "newsupp": "p" 
        }
     }
}
```

or

```
POST /q/q/AV4sjk40mWHLgYFNkmNd/_update
{
    "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "inline": "ctx._source.a.remove("1")"
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with single quotes, instead `"ctx._source.a.remove('1')"`

Comment: "ctx._source.a.remove('1')"  throwing error: "script": "ctx._source.a.remove('z')",
         "lang": "painless",
         "caused_by": {
            "type": "wrong_method_type_exception",
            "reason": "cannot convert MethodHandle(List,int)Object to (Object,String)Object"
         }
      }
   },

Comment: Sorry, try this instead `"ctx._source.a.removeIf(e -> e.equals('1'))"`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to remove all occurrences in the list, you can do this:

```
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": "ctx._source.a.removeAll(Collections.singleton('1'))"
  }
}
```

or if you want to remove just the first, like this:

```
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": "ctx._source.a.remove(ctx._source.a.indexOf('1'))"
  }
}
```

Also note that if you want to use double-quotes, it's fine, but you need to escape them, like `ctx._source.a.indexOf(\"1\"))`.

Or with params:

```
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": "ctx._source.a.remove(ctx._source.a.indexOf(yourParamName))",
    "params": {
      "yourParamName": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dshockley this worked great. Although, I did have to make one small change. I had to reference my param name by using 'params.yourParamName' like this `ctx._source.a.remove(ctx._source.a.indexOf(params.yourParamName))`

Comment: Any way to remove values based on wild card?

Comment: Will indexOf return -1 if index does not exists?