# Remove elements/objects From Array in ElasticSearch Followed by Matching Query

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, geolocation, match

I'm having issues trying to remove elements/objects from an array in elasticsearch.

This is the mapping for the index:

```
{
    "example1": {
        "mappings": {
            "doc": {
                "properties": {
                    "locations": {
                        "type": "geo_point"
                    },
                    "postDate": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "status": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "user": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is an example document.

```
{
    "_index": "example1",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "8036",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "user": "kimchy8036",
        "postDate": "2009-11-15T13:12:00",
        "locations": [
            [
                72.79887719999999,
                21.193036000000003
            ],
            [
                -1.8262150000000001,
                51.178881999999994
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Using the query below, I can add multiple locations.

```
POST /example1/_update_by_query
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "_id": "3"
        }
    },
    "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "inline": "ctx._source.locations.add(params.newsupp)",
        "params": {
            "newsupp": [
                -74.00,
                41.12121
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not able to remove array objects from locations. I have tried the query below but it's not working.

```
POST example1/doc/3/_update
{
    "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "inline": "ctx._source.locations.remove(params.tag)",
        "params": {
            "tag": [
                -74.00,
                41.12121
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly let me know where i am doing wrong here. I am using elastic version 5.5.2

Comment: Try using the _update_by_query instead of _update endpoint

Comment: I also tried  _update_by_query. But it also not working.
    POST /example1/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_id": "3"
    }
  },
"script" : {
  "lang":"painless",
         "inline": "ctx._source.locations.remove(params.newsupp)",
         "params":{
             "newsupp":[-74.00,41.12121 ]
         }}
    }

Answer (score 10):

In painless scripts, `Array.remove()` method removes by index, not by value.

Here's a working example that removes array elements by value in Elasticsearch script:

```
POST objects/_update_by_query
{
    "query": {
        ...  // use regular ES query to remove only in relevant documents
    },
    "script": {
        "source": """
            if (ctx._source[params.array_attribute] != null) {
                for (int i=ctx._source[params.array_attribute].length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    if (ctx._source[params.array_attribute][i] == params.value_to_remove) {
                        ctx._source[params.array_attribute].remove(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        """,
        "params": {
            "array_attribute": "<NAME_OF_ARRAY_PROPERTY_TO_REMOVE_VALUE_IN>",
            "value_to_remove": "<VALUE_TO_REMOVE_FROM_ARRAY>",
        }
    }
}
```

You might want to simplify script, if your script shall only remove values from one specific array attribute. For example, removing `"green"` from document's `.color_list` array:

```
_doc/001 = {
    "color_list": ["red", "blue", "green"]
}
```

Script to remove `"green"`:

```
POST objects/_update_by_query
{
    "query": {
        ...  // use regular ES query to remove only in relevant documents
    },
    "script": {
        "source": """
            for (int i=ctx._source.color_list.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                if (ctx._source.color_list[i] == params.color_to_remove) {
                    ctx._source.color_list.remove(i);
                }
            }
        """,
        "params": {
            "color_to_remove": "green"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Unlike `add()`, `remove()` takes **the index of the element** and remove it.

Your `ctx._source.locations` in painless is an `ArrayList`. It has `List`'s [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-) method:

> E remove(int index)
>
> Removes the element at the specified position in this list (optional operation). ...

See [Painless API - List](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/6.3/painless-api-reference.html#painless-api-reference-List) for other methods.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980054/how-to-remove-arraylist-value-in-elastic-search-using-curl) for example code.

Answer (score 0):

```
"script" : {
    "lang":"painless",
    "inline":"ctx._source.locations.remove(params.tag)",
    "params":{
      "tag":indexToRemove
    }
}
```

If with `ctx._source.locations.add(elt)` You add the element, with `ctx._source.locations.remove(indexToRemove)`, you remove by the index of element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
POST /your_index/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.your_array.removeIf(item -> item == params.value)",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "value": "value_to_remove"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "your_array": "value_to_remove"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is how you can write one line code to remove that element