# Elasticsearch - Delete query among nested object

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm new to Elasticsearch, and I cannot find a Delete query.

Here is an example of an document in myIndex :

```
{
  "_index": "myIndex",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "IPc5kn8Bq7SuVr5qM9dq",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "code": "1234567",
    "matches": [
      {
        "hostname": "hostnameA.com",
        "url": "https://www.hostnameA.com/....",
      },
      {
        "hostname": "hostnameB.com",
        "url": "https://www.hostnameB.com/....",
      },
      {
        "hostname": "hostnameC.com",
        "url": "https://www.hostnameC.com/....",
      },
      {
        "hostname": "hostnameD.com",
        "url": "https://www.hostnameD.com/....",
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Let's say this index contains 10k documents.

I would like a query to remove all the `item` from my array `matches` where the `hostname` is equal to `hostnameC.com`, and keeping all the others.

Anyone would have an idea to help me?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49384199/remove-elements-objects-from-array-in-elasticsearch-followed-by-matching-query

Comment: As mentioned above, you will succeed if you reproduce the suggestion. Don't forget to match like this:
ctx._source['matches'][i].hostname == 'hostnameC.com'