# Aggregation on .keyword to return only the keys that contain a specific string

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

New to aggregations in elasticsearch. Using 7.2. I am trying to write an aggregation on Tree.keyword to only return the count of documents that have a key that contains the word "Branch". I have tried sub aggregations, bucket_selector (which doesnt work for key strings) and scripts. Anyone have any ideas or suggestions on how to approach this?

Mapping:

```
{
  "testindex" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "Tree" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example Query that returns all the keys but what I need to do is limit to only return keys with "Branch" or better yet just the count of how many "Branch" keys there are:

```
GET testindex/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "bucket": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Tree.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Returns:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "testindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "Tree" : [
            "Car:76",
            "Branch:yellow",
            "Car:one",
            "Branch:blue"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "bucket" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Car:76",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "Branch:yellow",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "Car:one",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "Branch:blue",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should take a look at the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45982797/7674214

Answer (score 1):

You have to add includes for limit result. Here's the code sample and hopefully this should help you.

```
 GET testindex/_search
    {
    "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "Branch"
    ]
    },
      "aggs": {
        "bucket": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "Tree.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to filter the values for which buckets will be created. This can be done using the [include](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_4) and [exclude](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_regular_expressions_2) parameters which are based on regular expression strings or arrays of exact values. Additionally, **include** clauses that can filter using partition expressions.

For your case, it should be like this,

```
GET testindex/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "bucket": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Tree.keyword",
        "include": "Branch:*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help! Unfortunately, none of those solutions worked for me. I ended up using a script to return all the branches and then setting everything else into a new key. Then used a bucket script to subtract 1 in Total_Buckets. Probably a better solution out there but hopefully it helps someone

```
GET testindex/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "bucket": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "Tree.keyword",
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": "if(_value.contains('Branches:')) { return _value} return 1;"
        }
      }
    },
    "Total_Branches": {
      "bucket_script": {
        "buckets_path": {
          "my_var1": "bucket.value"
        },
        "script": "return params.my_var1-1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```