# Elasticsearch removing an array list when reindexing all records

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, reindex

So I am trying to reindex one of my indices to a temporary one and remove an array list: **platform.platforms.***

This is what my Kibana query looks like:

```
POST /_reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "devops-ucd-000001"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "temp-ucd"
  },

  "conflicts": "proceed",

  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": "ctx._source.platform.platforms.removeAll(Collections.singleton('1'))"
  }
}
```

However what I get is a null pointer exception:

```
"script_stack": [
  "ctx._source.platform.platforms.removeAll(Collections.singleton('1'))",
  "                    ^---- HERE"
],
"script": "ctx._source.platform.platforms.removeAll(Collections.singleton('1'))",
"lang": "painless",
"caused_by": {
  "type": "null_pointer_exception",
  "reason": null
}
```

I tried following this question: [how to remove arraylist value in elastic search using curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980054/how-to-remove-arraylist-value-in-elastic-search-using-curl) to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated here.

Answer (score 1):

It is  probably due to some documents not having platform field. You need to add additional checks in your script to ignore such  documents

```
"script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": """
                  if(ctx._source.platform!=null && ctx._source.platform.platforms!=null && ctx._source.platform.platforms instanceof List)
                  {
                    ctx._source.platform.platforms.removeAll(Collections.singleton('1'))
                  }
              """
  }
```

Above has null check on platform and platform.platforms also if platforms is of type list